# TextArea displaying the result just once

Tags: java, user-interface, textarea

When I take  the print of the for statement, it prints on the console 40 times but when i try to display that string on the textarea , it gives me the result just one time,Please why is this happening?Why textarea is creating this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably calling `setText(String t)` method in your for loop and therefore textArea's text is cleaned and filled with the new string element each time your loop executes. So eventually, you see the last string of the loop is printed in your textArea. You can use the following to append the new string to the previous text hold in your textArea component:

```
textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + " " + textToAppend);
```

Comment: Yes,  i am just writing textarea.setText(r);How do i write it the way you have told.I write it like textarea.setText(textarea.gettext()+r); as you suggested but it displays nothing

Comment: Hmm.. That's strange. `textarea.setText(textarea.gettext()+ " " +r);` should have worked for you in this case. Are you sure that 'r' is not null or there isn't other mistakes in your code? 

You can also consider using [StringBuffers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) to set your textArea's text only once, after it's shaped in StringBuffer.

Comment: Thanks it worked... i made a silly mistake that's why the results were not coming

Answer (score 1):

The results in the console are printed one at a time, but if you want to put the result in a textfield(multiple results) you should append the "result" string to the string contained in the textfield in each loop